# Loading Timer in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I have a timer on multiple cell which updates every second. how can i implement `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` in each cell. Is it possible to use single Timer which keeps track of the time of each cell. How can i implement this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the table view cells are made up of UI elements, I don't believe you can have dynamic timers as such. However, you could reload the table view every second, and you could set the timer to the appropriate value in each cell when reconfiguring the cells (which will happen after a call to [tableView reloadData]).

Comment: ok..so i need to reload table view each time in NSTimer method and update data accordingly.

Comment: Yes because you need to modify the label showing the time on each cell, every second.

Comment: You could also only reload the cells which need updating using:
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: (see the doc at:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40)